# How to split a char with "||" in elixir using regex?

Tags: regex, elixir

I'm trying to split a char using ||
Example: "ab||cd" = "aa","||","cd"
I tried with:

```
>>myString = String.split("aa||cd", ~r{(||?)})
```

But there is a problem cause i can't use | (is an elixir or regex token)
I need a regex cause I have some other regex clauses working. So...
How can i do it?

Comment: Looks like `~r{(\|\|?)}` is not what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression by escaping the `|` characters, and using `include_captures: true`:

```elixir
iex(1)> String.split("aa||bb", ~r{\|\|}, include_captures: true)
["aa", "||", "bb"]
```

A benefit of using Elixir however is that it makes regular expressions unnecessary in many situations. For example, you can do the same thing here using binaries and comprehensions, assuming the length of `aa` and `bb` is always 2:

```elixir
iex(2)> for <<i::binary-2 <- "aa||bb">>, do: i
["aa", "||", "bb"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.split("aa||cd", ~r/\b/)` will do the trick!

`\b` is a word boundary!

It will return `["aa", "||", "cd", ""]` in this case!